# Linear Regression in Esper - Group By

Tags: esper, nesper

[Esper](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/epl-views.html#view-stat-linest) provides a function of linear regression [stat:linest(*,*)].

Example looks like (and this works great):

```
    select * from StockTickEvent.win:time(10 seconds).stat:linest(price, offer)
```

However, I am trying to get a linear regression of all data in window grouped by symbol (say, INTC) and it does not allow me. I tried using "having symbol='GE'" and that was not right either. Here is what I tried to d:

```
    select * from StockTickEvent.win:time(10 seconds).stat:linest(current_timestamp(), price) group by symbol
```

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For grouping data windows the "std:groupwin" is the right approach.